# Calling a Javascript function after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function to which I am being passed a functionName that I need to call after making a ajax call. The ajax call is returning some html that contains a reference to a js file. The functionName being passed to my function is in the html but it is referencing an object in the js file. What I am noticing that the object sometimes exists and sometimes doesn't. Is there a way to ensure that the object always exists(or wait till it exists) and then only call the javascript function. Please note that I have no idea what the object variable is, so is there a way to ensure that the script file has been loaded in dom and then make the call to the function.

```
   function(functionName)
   {
      $.ajax({
    url: properties.url,
    type: properties.type,
    data: properties.data,
    dataType: properties.format,
    success: function (data) {
     // data contains <div>myname</div><script src="/myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     // Put the data in some div
     BindData(data);

     // How to ensure that the script myfile.js is loaded in dom before I call eval
     eval(functionName);
     }   );      

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your code for `GetAjaxData`?  The solution may require passing a callback for that function.

Comment: sorry..your right. the eval code is in the success part of the ajax call..I'll edit it above

Comment: try [`ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) method.

Comment: Also, is `functionName` really just a string with the name of a function?  If so, it's not going to execute without `()` on the end. Right now, you're just throwing the name of a variable into `eval`.  And if `functionName` is just a string with the name of function, just use `window[functionName]()` instead.

Comment: binding the data does not ensure that the script has been loaded in dom..so I want to call eval only if the script is loaded in dom

Comment: yes...If I just call the function and the object in myfile.js is not loaded in dom then an exception will be thrown. So, yes, how do I safely call the functionName function

Comment: You can do it right now -- just go to your profile and accept previous answers that helped you.  (Unless you found most answers in the past to be unhelpful, in which I apologize on behalf of Stack Overflow.)  Regardless, I'm working on an answer now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12049/discussion-between-kunal-ranglani-and-apsillers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function(functionName)
   {
      $.ajax({
    url: properties.url,
    type: properties.type,
    data: properties.data,
    dataType: properties.format,
    success: function (data) {
     // data contains <div>myname</div><script src="/myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     // Put the data in some div
     BindData(data);

    //ensure the script has loaded.
    $.getScript($('script:first',data).attr('src'), function(){
            eval(functionName);
    });

    });      

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to watch what is data before the ajax call end.
Not sure but, if data is "undefined" you can check something like this

```
var data = GetAjaxData();
while(typeof data === undefined);
bind, eval ecc ecc
```

But this will change if GetAjaxData return something else.
You can try the same thing but before do:

```
var data = null;
data = GetAjaxData();
while(data == null);
do stuff
```

You can also try $.ajax jquery with the success handler callback
Hope help